# BitmapSource vs DrawingImage

Tags: wpf, drawing, properties, pixel, bitmapsource

I know DrawingImage has a Drawing property to which we can set any of the Drawing sub-classes which represent a geometry with a brush and a pen. But where does BitmapSource store its pixels, in the MSDN documentation the description for BitmapSouce is:

> Represents a single, constant set of pixels at a certain size and resolution.

But I don't see any property for the set of pixels? By the way they both derive from ImageSource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BitmapSource` is a base class as well and, if you're looking to write pixel data on the fly you're looking for the [`WritableBitamp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) subclass.